# Confusion regarding RegExp matches, HTML tags, and newlines

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to create a Markdown-to-HTML parser. I am trying to use regex expressions to match an input string that may or may not contain HTML tags and whitespace/newlines. I have encountered an interesting case that I do not at all understand.

My regex expression is `regex = /\*([\w\s]+|<.+>)\*/g`.

The following works:

```
'*words\nmorewords*'.match(regex)
'*<b>words</b>*'.match(regex)
```

However, this does not work:

```
'*<b>words\nmore words</b>*'.match(regex)
```

If anyone can help me understand why this is so, I would appreciate it.

Edit: I see my faulty logic, thanks to Ry. The expression `regex = /\*(<[a-z]+>)?[\w\s]+(<\/[a-z]+>)?\*/g` solves this case.

Comment: `.` doesn’t match newlines without the `/s` flag. You can use `[^]` instead. Anything involving both regex and HTML is probably going to be fragile, though.

Comment: @Ry I'm not sure I understand. I don't have any whitespace within the tags themselves (i.e. between each set of `< >`), so why would that be relevant? Shouldn't the substring between HTML tags be handled by the first part of my regex, before the `|`?

Comment: `<.+>` was matching `<b>words</b>` all by itself. Did you intend to allow this group to repeat, and just have `<.+>` match the tag?

Comment: @Ry I can't believe I missed that... Yes, I was only trying to match the tags. I now see what the problem is, thank you. The solution still evades me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your purpose:

```
\*(<.+>)?([\w\s]+)(<.+>)?\*
```

The HTML tags can exist or not `(<.+>)?`. The `\n` is matched by the `\s` (whitespace).

I'm also going to link the canonical [don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) answer, because regex is not suitable for (or even capable of) parsing HTML beyond fairly restricted subsets. Have a read, it's informative (and funny)!

Recall the [Chomsky Heirarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). Regular expressions can parse regular languages. HTML is not a regular language (it is the next level up, context sensitive).

There are extensions to some regular expression engines that give it recursive capability. You can probably parse HTML with these but there are better ways, like using a proper HTML parser for example [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: Thank you! I used a slightly different solution, but it follows the same logic as your answer, and without the helpful links. 

In my case, this is more a personal exercise in regex than an actual HTML project (in fact the HTML is generated by the same function that parses it), but I will certainly keep the advice in mind for future projects.

Comment: Yep for sure, regex will work OK for simple stuff. :)